# Interrupt shell command line expansion

Tags: bash, command-line, kill, interrupt

**Warning: DO NOT attempt the commands listed in this question without knowing their implications.**

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I am surprised to learn that a command as simple as

```
echo $(yes)
```

freezes my computer (actually it is lagging the computer very badly rather than freezing, but the lag is bad enough to make one think it has frozen).  Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> right after typing this command does not seem to help me recover from this mistyped command.

On the other hand

```
ls /*/../*/../*/../*/../*/
```

is a well-known vulnerability that also lags the computer badly to the best and crashes the computer to the worst.

Note that these commands are quite different from the well-known fork bombs.

**My question is:** Is there a way to interrupt such commands which build up huge amount of shell command line options immediately after I start to execute them in the shell?

My understanding is that since shell expansion is done before the command is executed, the usual way to interrupt a command does not work because the command is not even running when the lag happens, but I also want to confirm that my understanding is correct, and I am extremely interested to learn any way to cancel the shell expansion before it uses too much memory.

I am not looking for how the kernel works at low memory. I am also not looking for `SysRq` overkills that may be helpful when the system already lags terribly. Nor am I looking for preventative approaches like imposing a `ulimit` on memory. I am looking for a way that can effectively cancel a huge shell expansion process from within the shell itself before it lags the system. I don't know whether it is possible. If it is impossible as commented, please also leave an answer indicating that, preferably with explanations.

I have chosen not to include any system-specific information in the original question because I want a general answer, but in case this matters, here are the information about my system: `Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS` with `gnome-terminal` and `bash 4.3.48(1)`, running a `x86_64` system. No virtual machines involved.

Comment: FWIW, I can cancel the globbing command without any difficulty on bash 4.4.18(1)-release (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: Did you use any terminal simulator?

Comment: If you mean a VM, yes, I'm running Ubuntu in Virtual Box on an MBP. But then, I have no problems cancelling the command on bash 4.4.19(1)-release on macOS on the same MBP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System hanging when it runs out of memory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28175/system-hanging-when-it-runs-out-of-memory)

Comment: You could set your shell process's memory ulimit to a suitable value.

Comment: Thank you. Why not turn it into an answer? Impossible is an answer too.

Comment: @muru I don't think that's a dupe. None of the answers there address the main question which is how this process can be stopped from within the shell that launched it. The SysRq-F suggestion isn't targeting the process and the other answers only discuss the cause, but offer no solution.

Comment: I can cancel the `ls` command easily immediately after launching, but if I let it run a few seconds, it takes multiple Ctrl+C to eventually kill it. @muru can you also cancel the `echo $(yes)` on your system?

Comment: @terdon not with `echo $(yes)`. And here, unlike with the globbing, there's simply high speed consumption of memory, and little you can do. What little there is is in that thread - summon the OOM killer, or set limits beforehand.

Comment: @terdon Just tested again. The behavior for globbing is as you said. It can be cancelled right away, but if I let it run a few seconds I need multiple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. On the other hand, I cannot cancel `echo $(yes)`, which means there are some difference between these two that I am interested to know.

Comment: @WeijunZhou the difference is most likely that the `$(yes)` command runs in a subshell and, I assume, doesn't return control to the parent shell until the command has finished. Since `yes` never finishes, control isn't returned. Not sure enough to post this as an answer though.

Comment: Running on a mac, I listed available terminal control sequences with `stty -a`, then was able to use `^t` to get the process identifier and kill it in another shell. I was unable to rescue the shell in either case.

Comment: Thank you for your information. There are not much info about Mac before you posted this.

Comment: You could try killing the bash process that's running the `echo` command.  Although, as @terdon pointed out, that may not work as expected due to the subshell process.

Comment: Thank you. If I haven't set a ulimit beforehand it seems that I have to respond really quickly to find out the PID and then kill the bash process before it lags my computer (it starts lagging within 5 secs for my box) at least for the 1st command.

Comment: I think `timeout` may solve your problem if you know the duration you expect it to run for. this will at-least stop computer from freezing.

Comment: Thank you for your information. I have tried it before and I think I may have better luck with the memory limitation using the timeout command. Anyway I am currently looking for a way to interrupt it from inside the shell, or a well-formed answer explaining why it is not possible. I think most of the comments so far, including yours, are helpful towards a final answer. I just need someone to combine them to an answer and I think I am not good enough at this topic to put all the pieces together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of `GNU bash, version 4.4.19(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` and I am not using a VM:

```
echo $(yes)
```

exists the shell and does not freeze the system, and:

```
ls /*/../*/../*/../*/../*/
```

returns

```
bash: /bin/ls: Argument list too long
```

But as a rule, when you dealing with something that could get all the resources of a system is better to set limits before running, if you know that a process could be a cpu hog you could start it with `cpulimit` or run `renice`.

If you want to limit the processes that are already started, you will have to do it one by one by PID, but you can have a batch script to do that like the one below:

```
#!/bin/bash
LIMIT_PIDS=$(pgrep tesseract)   # PIDs in queue replace tesseract with your name
echo $LIMIT_PIDS
for i in $LIMIT_PIDS
do
    cpulimit -p $i -l 10 -z &   # to 10 percent processes
done
```

In my case `pypdfocr` launches the greedy `tesseract`.

Also in some cases were your CPU is pretty good you can just use a `renice` like this:

```
watch -n5 'pidof tesseract | xargs -L1 sudo renice +19'
```